# Generating JSON from DataSet

Tags: c#, json, extjs4

I am working with ExtJS to generate a tree. It require JSON in the following format:

```
{  "children": [{
        "text": "Invisible",
        "expanded": true,
        "children": [{
            "text": "Billing",
            "leaf": true
        }, {
            "text": "Sales",
            "leaf": true
        }]
    },
    {
        "text": "Visible",
        "expanded": true,
        "children": [{
            "text": "Equipment",
            "leaf": true
        }, {
            "text": "Process",
            "leaf": true
        }]
    }]
}
```

The result I have in my DataSet is:

text                visible     leaf     expanded
Billing            0             true    false
Sales            0             true    false
Equipment    1             true    false
Process        1             true    false

All the records with visible = '1' should be generated under 'Visible' node and all the records with visible = '0' should be generated under 'Invisible' node. I am just not able to generate the JSON. How to generate it in the above said format?

Comment: What do you have so far? Take a look at linq to dataset http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386910(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with creating a complex type. I am posting the solution if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class as follows:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public bool leaf { get; set; }
    public bool expanded { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> children { get; set; }

    public TreeNode()
    {
        leaf = false;
        expanded = true;
        children = new List<TreeNode>();
    }
}
```

Based on the dataset returned I created the object as follows:

```
List<TreeNode> treeNodeList = new List<TreeNode>();
            treeNodeList.Add(new TreeNode
            {
                text = "Invisible",
                expanded = true,
                leaf = false
            });
            treeNodeList.Add(new TreeNode
            {
                text = "Visible",
                expanded = true,
                leaf = false
            });

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    treeNodeList[0].children.Add(new TreeNode
                                        {
                                            text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                                            leaf = true
                                        });
                }
            }

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    treeNodeList[1].children.Add(new TreeNode
                    {
                        text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                        leaf = true
                    });
                }
            }
            return treeNodeList;
```